# How to use Form tags in jsp to fetch properties from 2 Domain Objects and display in one form

Tags: mysql, eclipse

I am doing a project on Springs and Hibernate.

I have a problem which am stating below:

I have 2 entities (District and Address) and I wanted to display a form which contains properties of both entities using form tags in jsp.,for single entity I can do this with CommandName and can retrieve the form values,but if i want to include properties from 2 tables..

How can I do this???? Kindly help me...

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a model object that represents all the fields on the form. Then my model object would contain a District property and an Address property. You can then use nested property paths to access the properties of the nested object.

Comment: am not supposed to create other entity, i already hav one-one mapping between 2 entities?? why do i need to create one more entity???

Comment: I'm not talking about creating an Entity. Just a model object that backs your view and has references to the entities as nested properties. The contents of a given view don't always match up one-to-one with a single entity (as you have found out) but it is a good idea to have a single model object per view. This allows you to perform business logic within the model that is specific to the context in which the entities are being viewed/edited etc.

Comment: Hai, I have come out with other problem i.e i have a form which contains fields for adding say District name,District Code,Address1,pincode etc.and on listing them i have a update button for each District,so on clicking update i want to display a form which should show all these values by populating those values so that we can edit and update it..I want to do this using form tags in springs ...Kindly help...Thanks in advance..

Comment: That's a common requirement in a web app and Spring MVC provides the ability to do it. But its not a short answer. What I suggest is that you look at the reference documentation for Spring MVC and the form tag library and try and build your page. Then if you get a more specific problem, post a question on this site with your example code so that we can see what is going wrong. Good luck.